# Why "or ah,ah"?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm slowly trying to get into osdev just to play around.

[This tutorial](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/mixing-assembly-c) has a piece of assembly that waits for a drive to become ready:

```
reset_drive:
   mov ah, 0
   int 13h
   or ah, ah
   jnz reset_drive
```

I get that after the interrupt, `ah` will be zero if the device is ready. But what does `or ah,ah` do? Seems a bit redundant... it appears to do nothing. (at least by my logic) What does it do?

Comment: It's [an inefficient alternative to `test ah,ah`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/224132), which is especially bad for a high-8 register because writing them creates partial-register merging issues on Intel CPUs, even Skylake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sets/unsets the ZERO flag depending on whether `ah` is zero.

Depending on the status of the flag, `jnz reset_drive` will jump: Only if `ah` is *not* zero.

In other words, it waits for the device to become ready since it stops repeating after `ah` becomes zero.

Comment: oh wow. I didn't know about `ZF`. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @Matt Welcome, basically all arithmetic operations set/unset the `ZF` and the other flags, this is not exclusive to `or`.

Comment: I have experience with the dcpu-16 assembler, but not so hot on x86. dcpu is much easier to understand